# IIS not picking up override configured in Applicationhost.config

Tags: iis, configuration, web-config

While working with a web project in VS2012 on a win8 machine I have gotten an error that is quite commonly found on google, namely the
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

The solution mentioned everywhere is to locate the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config file and change the following:
section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow"

Alas, i still get exactly the same error.

**Things I have tried:**
Removing and reenabling IIS in the Windows features menu as this was mentioned as a solution.
Double checked that my app is running as an application, not virtual folder.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your not misinterpreting the section that cannot be accesed (error details should mention what section it is) and your app is adding handlers,  you could be running afoul of UAC vitualization.

The file gets a virtual version as you try to access it going forward this will be the version you allways get however the real file will still be served to IIS. A way to check is to trigger change that should be writen to aphost from IIS manager (such as windows authentication settings for app different from defaults) and see if you get it when viewing the file

The following goes into details on UAC including VirtualStore
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx

Try opening file under as admin, disabling UAC is also an option. You can aslo add handlers to your application using IIS manager and removed them from web.config.

Failing all that there are tools provided by IIS to manage configuration such as powershell module and command line.